# A variable not displayed on the screen after opening showmodalbottomsheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I'm still learning Flutter and I'm trying to display a variable "deliveryLocation2" on the screen after opening showmodalbottomsheet that bring the current location, but it stills stuck on the default value 'Detecting Location...' until performing hot reload, then it appears on the screen.

I want it to appear on the screen after a while from displaying the  'Detecting Location...' value

Also I want the 'circularProgressIndicator' to still on the screen alongside the 'Detecting Location...' value and disappear with it after displaying the current location

Note that I assigned the same value to an additional variable deliveryLocation2 because I want to search for the location again after opening showmodalbottomsheet, not only on initState method.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:talabato/constants.dart';
import 'package:talabato/screens/food_details.dart';
import 'package:talabato/screens/home/components/delivery_location.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String? deliveryLocation1, deliveryLocation2 ;
  
  @override
  void initState() {

deliveryLocation1 = deliveryLocation2 = 'Detecting Location...';

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    detectCurrentLocation();
  }

  Widget displayCurrentLocation(
      BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    return RichText(
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      text: const TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Delivering to\n',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }

  Future<String> _getAddressFromLocation(Position position) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        localeIdentifier: 'egy',
        position.latitude,
        position.longitude,
      );

      if (placeMarks.isNotEmpty) {
        Placemark placeMark = placeMarks.first;
        return placeMark.locality ?? "Unknown Location";
      } else {
        return "Unknown Location";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle errors
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Error getting address: $e");
      }
      return "Unknown Location";
    }
  }

  Future<String> detectCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      await Future.delayed(

        const Duration(seconds: 3),
      );
      Position position = await _determinePosition();
      String location = await _getAddressFromLocation(position);

      setState(() {
        deliveryLocation1 = location;
        deliveryLocation2 = location;
      });

      return location;
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle errors
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Error detecting location: $e");
      }
      setState(() {
        deliveryLocation1 = "Unknown Location";
        deliveryLocation2 = "Unknown Location";
      });
      return "Unknown Location";
    }
  }

  Future loadingIndicator(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 55,
                height: 55,
                child: circularProgressIndicator(6),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<dynamic> chooseDeliveryLocation() {

  

    return showModalBottomSheet(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            height: size.height * 0.45,
            width: size.width,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Choose delivery location',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const DeliveryLocation(
                    icon: Icons.location_on_outlined,
                    locationDetails:
                        'MVVM stands for Model-View-ViewModel. The basic idea is to create.',
                    locationName: 'Home',
                  ),
                 locationDetection(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                              onTap: () {
                                loadingIndicator(context);
                                // Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: DeliveryLocation(
                                icon: Icons.my_location,
                                locationName: 'Deliver to current location',
                                locationDetails: deliveryLocation2!,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 25,
                                  width: 25,
                                  child: circularProgressIndicator(3),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        
                      ),
                
                  const DeliveryLocation(
                    icon: Icons.pin_drop_outlined,
                    locationDetails:
                        'MVVM stands for Model-View-ViewModel. The basic idea is to create.',
                    locationName: 'Deliver to different location',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  FutureBuilder<String> locationDetection({Widget? child}) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: detectCurrentLocation(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return child!;
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // Handle error if any
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          // Display the actual location when detected
          return child!;
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: size.height * 0.35,
              color: const Color(0xFFFFCDB2),
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
   chooseDeliveryLocation();

    deliveryLocation2 = 'Detecting Location...';

                    
                      },
                      child: Text.rich(
                        TextSpan(
                          children: <InlineSpan>[
                            const TextSpan(
                              text: 'Delivering to\n',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            WidgetSpan(
                              child: locationDetection(
                                child: Text(
                                  deliveryLocation1!,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const FoodDetail(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.coronavirus_rounded))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope someone helps

Answer (score 0):

Add [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

```
String deliveryLocation1 = "".obs;
String deliveryLocation2 = "".obs;
```

when you use

```
Obx(() => Text("$deliveryLocation1"))
```